# How fill the vias_path field for restriction table

Tags: sql, postgresql, pgrouting

In [documentation](http://docs.pgrouting.org/2.2/en/doc/src/developer/sampledata.html?highlight=restriction) explain the restriction table for [pgr_trsp](http://docs.pgrouting.org/2.2/en/src/trsp/doc/pgr_trsp.html?highlight=restriction) function, and that way I can restrict left turn or right turn `{target_id, from_edge}`. But if I want to restrict multiple links it doesn't explain how fill the `via_path`

In this case all roads are one way, and you can't do the red turns. So `{2190, 2034, 673814}` and `{673814, 673816, 2190}` are forbidden.

**How I fill restriction table?**

[image]

```
CREATE TABLE restrictions (
    rid BIGINT NOT NULL,
    to_cost FLOAT,
    target_id BIGINT,
    from_edge BIGINT,
    via_path TEXT
);

COPY restrictions (rid, to_cost, target_id, from_edge, via_path) FROM stdin WITH NULL '__NULL__' DELIMITER ',';
1,100,7,4,__NULL__
1,100,11,8,__NULL__
1,100,10,7,__NULL__
2,4,8,3,5
3,100,9,16,__NULL__
\.
```

Comment: @vicky can you be more specific?

Answer (score 1):

The complete query in the example in the documentation that uses the table like the posted one:

```
SELECT * FROM pgr_trsp(
    'SELECT id::INTEGER, source::INTEGER, target::INTEGER, cost FROM edge_table',
    2, 7, false, false,
    'SELECT to_cost, target_id::int4,
    from_edge || coalesce('','' || via_path, '''') AS via_path
    FROM restrictions'
);
```

So the table that you posted is used like this in that query:

```
'SELECT to_cost, target_id::int4,
 FROM edge || coalesce('','' || via_path, '''') AS via_path
```

So, back to square one, how to fill the table:

From the documentation:

- restrict_sql: (optional) a SQL query, which should return a set of rows with the following columns:

  SELECT to_cost, target_id, via_path FROM restrictions
- to_cost:  float8 turn restriction cost
- target_id:    int4 target id
- via_path: text comma separated list of edges in the reverse order of rule

It never mentions if the target_id is an edge or a vertex, so based on the via_path, I'll suppose its an edge:

```
CREATE TABLE restrictions (
  rid BIGINT NOT NULL,
  to_cost FLOAT8,
  target_id BIGINT,
  via_path TEXT
);
```

From your image this are forbidden turns (all ids are edges):

- 637814 -> 637816 -> 2190
- 2190 -> 2034 -> 637814

I would insert the data to that table like this:

```
INSERT INTO restrictions (rid, target_id, via_path) VALUES
 (1, 300, 2190, '637816, 637814'),
 (2, 300, 637814, '637814, 2034');
```

So, these restrictions do not allow those U-turn, but still allow the following Left turns:

- 637814 -> 637816
- 2190 -> 2034

Using it with this new table:

```
SELECT * FROM pgr_trsp(
    'SELECT id::INTEGER, source::INTEGER, target::INTEGER, cost FROM edge_table',
    2, 7, false, false,
    'SELECT to_cost, target_id::int4, via_path'
    FROM restrictions'
);
```

Notes:

- My understanding of the documentation on that particular function is very limited.
- I don't understand the advantages of having the design of the table *restrictions* the way the documentation has it.
- There is no advantage on the table *restrictions* as I propose it here.

Comment: So you can remove the `from_edge` field?

Comment: I saw your github, are you working in the next pgrouting release?